# Convert datacontract to dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, type-conversion

I would like to convert a strong type object into a dynamic. How can I achieve this?

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "birth_date")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public void someFunction()
    {
        var p = new Person {Name = "Hans", BirthDate = new DateTime(1999, 11, 1)};

        var p2 = ConvertToDynamic(p);

        Assert.That(p2.name, Is.SameAs("Hans"));
        Assert.That(p2.birth_date, Is.SameAs(new DateTime(1999, 11, 1)));
    }

    private static dynamic ConvertToDynamic(Person person)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

A quick and dirty approach might be to use a serializer for that. Is there something better?

I would like to avoid instanciating an ExpandoObject and set every single property by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would do it:

```
private static dynamic ConvertToDynamic(Person person)
{
    return person as dynamic;
}
```

Or you could try retrurning an anonymous type:

```
private static dynamic ConvertToDynamic(Person person)
{
    return new { person.Name, person.BirthDate };
}
```